# How can I run many concurrent commands using QProcess with c ++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, qprocess

I edited the code, The "deneme" variable is a command in the setup.csh file. In the setup.ssh "deneme" command: alias deneme "ls -la". My purpose is to run a command guide in that setup.csh.

Termainal command: 
[intern2atlas SETUP]$ source setup.csh 
output : /sw/mentor/questasim/10.4a.2 
[intern2atlas SETUP]$ deneme 
Output: -rw-r----- intern2 Domain Users 4096 Nov 8 14:56 setup.csh,
(I want to run these commands simultaneously with QProcess)

I want to run the "deneme" command in setup.csh

```
QProcess *process1=new QProcess(this);
process1->setWorkingDirectory("/home/intern2/elif/SETUP");

process1->start("tcsh",QStringList() <<"-c"<<"\"\"source /home/intern2/elif/SETUP/setup.csh\"\"" << "deneme" );

process->waitForBytesWritten();
process1->waitForFinished();
ui.textedit->append(process.readAllStandartOutput());
```

"deneme" command not working

Gui code and output

[image]

Output:

[image]

Terminal output:

[image]

Comment: The code as posted will not compile -- `process1` is a pointer.  The second parameter to `QProcess::start` should be a `QStringList` containing separate args not a single `QString`.  Please post an [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I made the necessary corrections and additions @G.M.